# is this linkedlist code a good practice?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

Hi everyone I am a newbie in C and trying to learn it. I have a simple query regarding this linkedlist implementation which I found at many places:

```
void addNode(node **listhead, int data, int pos){
        if(pos<=0 || pos > length(*listhead)+1){
                printf("Invalid position provided, there are currently %d nodes in the list \n", length(*listhead));
                return;
        }else{
                node *current = *listhead;
                node *newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
                if(newNode == NULL){
                        printf("Memory allocation error\n");
                        return;
                }
                newNode->data = data;
                newNode->next = NULL;
                if (current == NULL){
                        *listhead = newNode;
                        return;
                }else{
                        int i = 0;
                        while(current->next != NULL && i < pos-1){
                                ++i;
                                current = current->next;
                        }
                        if(current->next == NULL){
                                current->next = newNode;
                        }
                        if(i == pos-1){
                                newNode->next = current->next;
                                current->next = newNode;
                        }
                }
        }
}




int main(){
        node *head = NULL;
        node **headref = &head;
        addNode(headref, 1, 1);
        addNode(headref, 2, 2);
        addNode(headref, 3, 3);
        printList(head);
        return 0;
    }
```

my query is here we are creating a pointer to a pointer which is pointing to NULL. This code works, however I wanted to know if this is a good practice. If it is not, how should I create my head pointer and pass its reference to the addNode function.

Comment: This is not a link list implementation. This is the usage of a linked list. And there's no problem with using NULL pointers (they're in the language for a reason), but it's hard to tell what all this is doing without more context and actual, **relevant** code.

Comment: If you don't like `headref`, you can also use `addNode(&head, 1, 1)`. In general, there isn't a specific bad practice about this code.

Comment: I updated code with addNode function too. Thanks for responding, I think I understood, just have stupid fear of pointers. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1772218 - that's alright: C++ bigots often say lots of nasty things about pointers ;)

Comment: @paulsm4 Yup, and fortunately this is not C++ just plain ol' C, so it's completely valid and good practice to use pointers if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggested alternative:

```
int main() {
  node *head = addNode(NULL, 1, 1);
  node *current = head;
  current = addNode(current, 2, 2);
  current = addNode(current, 3, 3);
  printList(head);
  return 0;
}
```

In other words:

1) addNode() becomes a function that takes the current value as a parameter (so it doesn't have to traverse the entire list just to add a new element)...

2) ... and it returns a pointer to the new node.

3) This means at *ANY* point in the program you can access *ANY* of a) the list head, b) the previous pointer (before "add") and/or c) the next pointer (after add).

Comment: Assuming addNode is re-written to return the added node rather than as an out-param?

Comment: This is something I never thought of. thank god I asked. This is really good implementation.

Comment: @user1772218 it is a completely different design than yours. Yours is designed to take a list-head and insert a node a a specific position (think of it as an ordinal index). This does not, and the position parameter  is useless unless used as a *relative* offset to the `current` node.

Comment: Yes, However I find it a good alternative design, I would not have thought of returning the pointer to the next node. I am learning and this is just a sample code.  So It is good to learn an alternative method and use it when I don't have to bother about inserting a node in between, and just have to add a node in the end.

Answer (score 0):

We pass a double pointer to addNode() for cases, where the headref pointer needs to be updated. For such cases, with "addNode(headref, 1, 1);", the addNode would most likely be storing the address of the malloced element inside addNode() in the headref. If you were to pass headref as a pointer, then after the call headref would continue to point to the address in the main and you would lose the malloced address.

Answer (score 0):

For single linked list, it is actually a good practice, which simplifies the addNode implementation. 
I guess the call to `addNode(node_x, 1, 1)` will add a node before `node_x`. If you pass only the pointer to `node_x`. Then the function will need to loop over the entire list and find the node before `node_x` and modify its pointer to the new constructed node. While if you pass a pointer to pointer, let's say `node** p` then the function only needs to assign the address of the new node to `*p`.